# Conditional type for additional constraint on enum mapping

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-types

In my project I have two enums `SourceEnum` and `TargetEnum`. For both of the enums, a function exists, which is called with some parameters that depend on the enum value. The exact type of the expected parameters is defined by the two type mappings `SourceParams` and `TargetParams`.

```js
enum SourceEnum {
  SOURCE_A = 'SOURCE_A',
  SOURCE_B = 'SOURCE_B'
}

enum TargetEnum {
  TARGET_A = 'TARGET_A',
  TARGET_B = 'TARGET_B',
}

interface SourceParams {
  [SourceEnum.SOURCE_A]: { paramA: string };
  [SourceEnum.SOURCE_B]: { paramB: number };
}

interface TargetParams {
  [TargetEnum.TARGET_A]: { paramA: string };
  [TargetEnum.TARGET_B]: { paramB: number };
}

function sourceFn<S extends SourceEnum>(source: S, params: SourceParams[S]) { /* ... */ }

function targetFn<T extends TargetEnum>(target: T, params: TargetParams[T]) { /* ... */ }
```

I have a mapping that contains a function to evaluate a target value for each source value and what I want to do is, ensure that the `params` object used to call `sourceFn(x, params)` will also work for the call `targetFn(mapping[x](), params)`. To achive this, I created this type:

```js
type ConstrainedMapping = {
  [K in SourceEnum]: <T extends TargetEnum>() => (SourceParams[K] extends TargetParams[T] ? T : never) 
};

const mapping: ConstrainedMapping = {
  [SourceEnum.SOURCE_A]: () => TargetEnum.TARGET_A;
  // ...
}
```

But then defining the `mapping` like above gives me the following error:

```
Type 'TargetEnum.TARGET_A' is not assignable to type '{ paramA: string; } extends TargetParams[T] ? T : never'.
```

My typing looks clear to me, so I don't really understand what the problem is here. I suppose typescript isn't capable of narrowing down the exact enum value at some point.

Is there a way to achive this? I'm currently working on Typescript 4.2, but I also tried it on 4.3 and 4.4-beta and all show the same behavior. A solution in 4.2 would be highly appreciated, but also a solution in a future version would be fine by me.

Comment: Please provide more examples with calling `targetFn(mapping[x](), params)` and `sourceFn(x, params)`. Where did you get `x`?

Comment: `x` is just meant to be an arbitrary value of type `SourceEnum` here. The two functions actually aren't too relevant. I just wanted to show in a practical way that `SourceParams[typeof x]` should be assignable to `TargetParams[typeof mapping[x]()]` for any `x: SourceEnum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are expecting here is for Typescript to see `<T extends TargetEnum>(): SourceParams[K] extends TargetParams[T] ? T : never;`, and then distribute all possible values of `T` into this condition and create a union of the ones where it is true.

Problem is, Typescript isn’t doing that. It’s treating `T` as unknown, and not evaluating this expression any further than substituting `{ paramA: string; }` for `SourceParams[K]`. The kind of distribution you’re looking for only occurs in [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). So we have to rewrite your `ConstrainedMapping` to use one.

A Distributive Conditional Type is a conditional type alias in which none of the parameters are constrained. So to begin with, we need an actual `type` declaration for this return value, we can’t just put it in the larger declaration of `ConstrainedMapping`. (Yes, this is weird—the fact that types behave differently if pulled out into its own alias is one of my biggest problems with Typescript’s design.) Like so:

```
type TargetWithMatchingParams<S, T> =
  S extends SourceEnum
    ? T extends TargetEnum
      ? SourceParams[S] extends TargetParams[T]
        ? T
        : never
      : never
    : never;
```

We can’t constrain `S` or `T`, so we have to use more conditions within the template for that. (Yes, this is also weird; it’s rather counter-intuitive for that to change the behavior like this.) We also can’t simply hardcode the entire `TargetEnum` here, even though that’s ultimately what we want—the distribution has to be across an unconstrained param to the type alias.

When we have done *that*, then we can use it in `ConstrainedMapping`:

```
type ConstrainedMapping = {
  [S in SourceEnum]: () => TargetWithMatchingParams<S, TargetEnum>;
};
```

Note that the function is no longer generic—that was part of your problem—and that we achieve the distribution you were looking for, instead, by passing `TargetEnum` into `TargetWithMatchingParams`.

By the way, if your real case is static like your example, removing the `() =>`  from the definition of `ConstrainedMapping` and “calling” `mapping` with `mapping[x]` instead of `mapping[x]()` would be marginally more performant, and arguably easier to read.

**Finally**, there are a couple of limitations to be aware of here.

1. Calling `mapping` on a generic variable that `extends SourceEnum` doesn’t work. That is, `targetFn(mapping[SourceEnum.SOURCE_A](), { paramA: 'foo' })` works, but Typescript chokes on something like this:

   ```
   function bar<S extends SourceEnum>(src: S, params: SourceParams[S]) {
     targetFn(mapping[src](), params);
                              ^^^^^^
   //                         Argument of type 'SourceParams[S]'
   //                           is not assignable to parameter of type
   //                           'TargetParams[ConstrainedMapping[S]]'.
   }
   ```

   That is, Typescript isn’t smart enough to truly *understand* the relationship between `SourceParams` and `TargetParams`, and won’t be able to recognize that any valid `SourceParams` value will always match the corresponding `TargetParams`.
2. In a situation where we accept a union of sources and a union of source params, basically the non-generic version of the above, Typescript allows unsafe values. Consider:

   ```
   function baz(src: SourceEnum, params: SourceParams[SourceEnum]) {
     targetFn(mapping(src), params);
   }
   baz(SourceEnum.SOURCE_A, { paramB: 42 });
   ```

   This will not cause any errors, even though we have `SOURCE_A` and `paramB` and that’s an invalid combination. Ultimately, though, this is just a limitation on how Typescript unions work—the problem is in the definition of `baz`, or the definition of `SourceParams`/`TargetParams`, and would be exactly the same if `baz` called `sourceFn` without `mapping` entering into it at all.

The too-long, didn’t-read version here is just make sure you call `sourceFn` and `targetFn` with a specific enum type, not the whole enum. Typescript doesn’t keep track of relationships between separate variables, so it won’t be checking if your unknown `SourceEnum` and unknown `SourceParams[SourceEnum]` actually go together, and no definition of `mapping` is going to solve that problem.